# Changing a string of characters to a user-set values

Tags: java, string, char

I need help changing a string of characters (doesn't matter what, I've been using a specific set you'll see below) to set numbers. The "technique" is to replace each letter with the place it is in the alphabet. We will use two digits for every letter. For example, the letter ‘a’ is 01, the letter ‘b’ is 02, the letter ‘c’ is 03, the letter ‘z’ is 26. So that we can use capital letters we start ‘A’ with 27, ‘B’ with 28, ‘C’ with 29, and so on.

For numbers, we convert each digit into two letters: the first two letters that they stand for. The first letter is capitalized followed by a lower-case letter. For example, 8 written out is eight. So, 8 would be encrypted to “Ei”, 1 would be encrypted to “On”,2 would be encrypted to “Tw”, 3 would be “Th” and so on. Note that “10” is actually two digits, so it would be encrypted as “1” and “0”: “OnZe”If you come to a non-letter character (spaces, punctuation, numbers, etc.), just print them as is without encrypting.

I began using the following code:

```
public class Try{

   public static void main (String[] args){

      System.out.println("hello");
      String string = "Orange juice is great! I drank 83,214 cups of it yesterday.";
      System.out.print(string); //to see the string is appropriately done
      char exampleChar = 'a';
      int charCastAsInt = (int) exampleChar;
      System.out.print(charCastAsInt);
   }
}
```

I don't know how to parse through the string, ignoring special characters and spaces while still printing them in their place and getting each number to print what I tell it each value should be. Should I use a for loop? And then go on from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start :

- `0` is represented by `48`
- `9` is represented by `57`
- `a` is represented by `97`
- `z` is represented by `122`
- `A` is represented by `65`
- `Z` is represented by `90`

From this we can loop over the String using `.toCharArray()` and check the range of each character :

```
String string = "Orange juice is great! I drank 83,214 cups of it yesterday.";
String[] numbers = {"Ze", "On", "Tw", "Th", "Fo", "Fi", "Si", "Se", "Ei", "Ni"};
String result = "";
for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
    if (c >= 48 && c <= 57) {// range [0-9] digits
        result += numbers[c - 48];
    } else if (c >= 97 & c <= 122) {// range [a-z] lower letters
        result += String.format("%02d", (char) c - 96);
    } else if (c >= 65 & c <= 90) {// range [A-Z] upper letters
        result += c - 38;
    }else {
        result += c;
    }
}

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
411801140705 1021090305 0919 0718050120! 35 0418011411 EiTh,TwOnFo 03211619 1506 0920 250519200518040125.
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't tell you the whole answer since this seems to be homework. But here are some hints:

- `"aString".charAt(i)` gives you the charater at the given index
- `"aString".length()` gives you the number of charcters in the string

Now use some [loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [if-else-statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) and you are done...

Answer (score 0):

Class ***String*** has a lot of methods and I would suggest you to look at ***toCharArray()***. That method returns *char array* through which you can loop, cast each item to **int** type and print the result. That could be written like this:

```
for (char c : "Some string".toCharArray()) System.out.print((int) c + " ");
```

**Output:** 83 111 109 101 32 115 116 114 105 110 103